# How to rewrite an expression

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Let's say $Z=Y_1+Y_2$. I have this expression: $Y_1!Y_2!$. I want to rewrite the expression and express it by only $Z$. Is that possible?

Comment: No, because $Y_1=5$, $Y_2=7$ and $Y_1=4$, $Y_2=8$ give the same $Z$ but different $Y_1!Y_2!$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because for example if you take $Y_1=5$, $Y_2=7$ or if you take $Y_1=4$, $Y_2=8$, then both give the same $Z$ but different $Y_1!Y_2!$.

Answer (score -1):

Not possible. Consider $Z=4$ with $Y_1 = 1$ and $Y_2 = 3$, you'll get an answer of $6$. Now try this with $Y_1 = 2$ and $Y_2 = 2$, you'll get an answer of $4$.

Comment: Hmm I think you misunderstood what I said. I basically just want to know if you can rewrite Y1!Y2! and only use the term (Y1+Y2). It's probably just med who are bad at expressing myself